# Detect mismatches in two data frames based on a specific column

Tags: r, dplyr, matching

I have to data frames with ratings of two independent rater. In column x the year of publication for papers with a certain reference ID (Ref.ID) was coded. For some paper, multiple samples were coded. This information is reflected in the variable "Sample.ID" (e.g., in df1 there are three samples coded for Ref.ID "C"). A combination of reference ID and sample ID is represented in variable "Ref.Sample.ID". I would like so know for which Ref.Sample.ID's the coding of variable x differs between df1 and df2. Note that df2 has one row less than df1, because the rater in df2 only coded two samples for Ref.ID "C", whereas the rater in df1 coded three samples.

I'm trying to find an R code that will expose the mismatches between df1 and df2. Mismatches can occur either because a different number of rows per Ref.ID was coded or because x differs between df1 and df2 for the same Ref.Sample.ID.

Does anyone know how to do this best? I am happy for every hint :)

```
df1 <- read.table(text="
  Ref.ID    Sample.ID    Ref.Sample.ID     x       y
  A         1            A-1               2000    a    
  B         1            B-1               1992    a
  C         1            C-1               2018    b 
  C         2            C-2               2018    b   
  C         3            C-3               2018    b   
  D         1            D-1               2011    c 
  D         1            D-1               2011    c
  E         1            E-1               1990    a      
  F         1            F-1               1990    c   
  G         1            G-1               2015    d   
  G         2            G-2               2015    d    
  G         3            G-3               2015    d", header=TRUE)

# Note df2 has one row less than df1!

df2 <- read.table(text="
  Ref.ID    Sample.ID    Ref.Sample.ID     x       y     
  A         1            A-1               2000    a   
  B         1            B-1               1992    a
  C         1            C-1               2018    b
  C         2            C-2               2018    b   
  D         1            D-1               2011    a 
  D         2            D-2               2011    a
  E         1            E-1               1991    a       
  F         1            F-1               1990    d   
  G         1            G-1               2011    d    
  G         2            G-2               2011    d     
  G         3            G-3               2011    c", header=TRUE)
```

The final result should be different vectors of Ref.Sample.ID for which there are differences between df1 and df2 on x or y.

E.g. 
For x:
"C-3" "E-1" "G-1" "G-2" "G-3" "D-2"

For y:
"C-3" "D-1" "F-1" "G-3" "D-2"

Comment: I think I need two things. First, I need a check like this: IF df1$ref.sample.id == df2$ref.sample.id, THEN df1$x == df2$x. If this is FALSE, then I would like to see the ref.sample.id for which it was false. Second, I need a check whether in df1 and df2 the same number of rows is coded per ref.id. If this is not the case, I would like to see the ref.id for which this was not the case.

Comment: Yes, that would do it, I think.

Comment: try something like: `unique(bind_rows(anti_join(df1, df2), anti_join(df2, df1))[["Ref.Sample.ID"]])` ... requires `library(dplyr)`

Comment: Cool, it worked :) However, what if I have another variable y for which I would also like to check the ratings. Again, I would like to see a vector of Ref.Sample.ID but I would also like to know whether the "mismatch" was on column x or y. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Sure, I updated my original post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will use both `tidyr` and `dplyr`.

You can `pivot_longer` first for both data frames so you will have a separate row for `x` and `y` to compare. Then use `anti_join` to find differences between the 2 data frames. This will check for extra/missing/different rows in either data frame.

Finally, to get your final result, you can filter by `x` or `y`, select `Ref.Sample.ID` as your column of interest, and `distinct()` to remove duplicates. An alternative is to use `group_by(var)` instead of `filter` if you want all results together in a data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1_long <- pivot_longer(df1, cols = c(x, y), names_to = "var", values_to = "val", values_ptypes = list(val = 'character'))
df2_long <- pivot_longer(df2, cols = c(x, y), names_to = "var", values_to = "val", values_ptypes = list(val = 'character'))

df_diff <- bind_rows(anti_join(df1_long, df2_long), anti_join(df2_long, df1_long))

df_diff %>%
  filter(var == "x") %>%
  select(Ref.Sample.ID) %>%
  distinct()
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  Ref.Sample.ID
  <chr>        
1 C-3          
2 E-1          
3 G-1          
4 G-2          
5 G-3          
6 D-2
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Ref.ID = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", 
"E", "F", "G", "G", "G"), Sample.ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Ref.Sample.ID = c("A-1", "B-1", "C-1", 
"C-2", "C-3", "D-1", "D-1", "E-1", "F-1", "G-1", "G-2", "G-3"
), x = c(2000L, 1992L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2011L, 2011L, 1990L, 
1990L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), y = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", 
"c", "a", "c", "d", "d", "d")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

df2 <- structure(list(Ref.ID = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", 
"F", "G", "G", "G"), Sample.ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Ref.Sample.ID = c("A-1", "B-1", "C-1", "C-2", 
"D-1", "D-2", "E-1", "F-1", "G-1", "G-2", "G-3"), x = c(2000L, 
1992L, 2018L, 2018L, 2011L, 2011L, 1991L, 1990L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L), y = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "d", "d", "d", 
"c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```